# Use iframe for mvvm design pattern

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mvvm, knockout.js

Is it a good idea to use iframe for mvvm pattern? I am currently using knockout js to similate the mvvm design pattern in c#. I am thinking of making independent components into their own html  files (view) with a corresponding .js file (model) for them, and render them using an iframe whenever a pages needs them. This way I can create many reusable components.

Can any one please explain in details the pros and cons of doing so? Thanks

Comment: If you are wanting to make reusable components it may be worth looking into [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/). Polymer allows you to define custom HTML elements that encapsulates the JS and CSS needed for that component.

Answer (score 0):

Using frames in any web development, especially for the important parts of the page, is a bad idea. They should be used only for embedding 3rd party plugins (like a shoutbox). For other stuff you should use partial postbacks with ajax instead (if you need that kind of behavior). You can create reusable parts/controls with both MVC and Webforms frameworks, so you shouldn't have any problems.

If you need to know why exactly frames are a bad idea, simply google it, there has been way too many talks about it already.